# Cakephp 2.x REST

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I would develop a service restful with cakephp 2.0 but I can't.

I receive this message after following the official documentation

The error message :

```
Warning (2): SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [simplexmlelement.--construct]: Entity: line 3: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document [CORE\Cake\Utility\Xml.php, line 177]
Warning (2): SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [simplexmlelement.--construct]: <response><Hotel><id>1041114</id><hotelFileName>Argana_Hotel</hotelFileName><hot [CORE\Cake\Utility\Xml.php, line 177]
Warning (2): SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [simplexmlelement.--construct]: ^ [CORE\Cake\Utility\Xml.php, line 177]

CakePHP: the rapid development php framework
```

String could not be parsed as XML

```
Error: An Internal Error Has Occurred.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just ran into the same problem trying to implement RestKit from github.

Seems like the problem occurs when I pass multiple variables to the _serialize parameter.

Think it is because xml should be wrapped in a main container.

Nesting my content in a wrapper seemed to fix this error for me.

```
Broken Example:
<items>
  <item>data</item>
  <item>data</item>
<items>
<categories>
 <category>data</category>
</categories>

Working Example:
<response>
  <items>
    <item>data</item>
    <item>data</item>
  <items>
  <categories>
   <category>data</category>
  </categories>
</response>
```

Just changed:

```
$this->set('data', $this->viewVars);
$this->set('_serialize', array('data'));
```

To:

```
$this->set('data', array('data'=>$this->viewVars));
$this->set('_serialize', array('data'));
```